# Is it possible to reverse engineer the metric to find the basis vectors of the manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors

For a given surface that has metric components $g_{\mu\nu}$ is it possible to find it's basis vectors and more importantly the exact surface that space is on. Since we know that
$$g_{\mu\nu} = e_\mu \cdot e_\nu$$

However, for an intrinsic geometry, the transformation that gives it its geometry is given by a general transformation $x'^\mu b_\mu = G^\mu(x^\mu) b_\mu$ if we take the partial derivative with respect to $x^\nu$ we get that
$$e_\nu=\partial_\nu G^\mu(x^\mu) b_\mu$$
The new space that these intrinsically curved coordinates live in is measured with orthogonal basis vectors $b_\mu$. This gives us
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu G^\alpha(x^\mu) b_\alpha \cdot \partial_\nu G^\beta(x^\mu) b_\beta$$
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu G^\alpha(x^\mu) \partial_\nu G^\beta(x^\mu) b_\alpha \cdot b_\beta$$
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu G^\alpha(x^\mu) \partial_\nu G^\beta(x^\mu) \delta_{\alpha\beta}$$

With this information is it possible to find the transformation $G^\mu(x^\mu)$ in terms of the metric components?

Comment: This question is very unclear

Comment: @magma For a transformation $x'^\mu e_\mu = G^\mu(x^\alpha) b_\mu$ which curves the coordinates. The tangent vectors of the space is  $e_\nu = \partial_\nu x'^\mu b_\mu = \partial_\nu G^\mu(x^\alpha) b_\mu$. Where the $b_\mu$ basis vectors are orthogonal and form the metric $\delta_{\mu\nu} = b_\mu \cdot b_\nu$. So that the basis vectors of the curved space is $g_{\mu\nu} = e_\mu \cdot e_\nu$ but we know what the curved basis vectors, so this means that $g_{\mu\nu} =  \partial_\mu G^\alpha(x^\gamma) \partial_\nu G^\beta(x^\gamma) \delta_{\alpha\beta}$. Can we find $G^\beta(x^\gamma)$?

Comment: @magma if we know $g_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Your eqs are incorrect,  as far as I understand them.  Where are you studying from?  In any case your question does not make sense.  There are infinite basis vectors that satisfy any given metric.

Comment: @magma How are the tangent basis vectors incorrect? Because if it was embedded in higher dimensions it would work eg. the surface of the sphere

Comment: @magma If there are an infinite amount of basis vectors that satisfy a metric, then what equation do they have to satisfy?

Comment: I asked you : where are you studying these things from?

Comment: @magma The basis vector derivation comes from (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmjbpIgVKFs&list=PLJHszsWbB6hpk5h8lSfBkVrpjsqvUGTCx&index=14) [timeStamp = 11:23]. I used it for a 2d transformation instead of a 3d. I assumed it would be correct if it works to derive the metric for a sphere. Thanks